# What happens to all policy exemptions after deleting a policy assignment?

Tags: azure, azure-policy

What happens to all exemptions attached to a policy after the policy is deleted?

Comment: when you create a policy exemption at resource group scope for a policy assignment at the same or above level, the exemption exempts to all applicable resources in the resource group.



The policy exemptions isn't deleted when the `expiresOn` date is reached. The object is preserved for record-keeping, but the exemption is no longer honored.

Comment: okay, so essentially, I need to go through all the orphaned exemptions and remove them to delete them? they won't delete themself?